# Spice Simulation Models?

Tags: simulation, spice, eda

Where can one go to find SPICE models? I am curious if there is a giant repository out there somewhere that I can search?

In particular, I am looking for a model for an LM317 voltage regulator, at the moment. However, I can't find this on Linear's site and I am not having much luck with the other manufacturers for their parts. It seems like this would be a very common problem for designers wishing to simulate their circuits?

Thanks!

Comment: This path may have what need from the manufacturer http://www.ti.com/product/LM317/toolssoftware#model

Answer (score 4):

Usually if I need a model that's not in LTSpice, I go onto the manufacturers website (LM means National Semiconductor so you would try there in this case) and type the part number in then look under tools/models on the part's page.
Here's a random example for the [LM7732](http://www.national.com/pf/LM/LMP7732.html#Tools).

If that doesn't work then google "spice [part number]" often turns something up.

For the LM317, the first technique didn't work, but google turned a TI model up, linked to in one of the posts on [this page](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/general-electronics-chat/95782-how-use-lm317-ltspice-model.html).

Answer (score 3):

There are a few options for finding simulation models.

Generally, if you have a specific part in mind, you should check the manufacturer site first. There will usually be a section called "Support" or something like that and in this section of the site the manufacturer will provide SPICE models. I have developed a fairly large repository of components just by going to the major manufacturer websites and downloading their parts libraries.

If it is a more general part (such as your LM317) you can sometimes find parts that are similar enough that they can be substituted in a SPICE simulation.

Finally, if all else fails, you can make your own models. This probably won't help you much for a linear regulator, but when you have transistors, diodes or other SPICE primitives, you can get the necessary information from a datasheet a use a .MODEL command to create your own model. For more information on using the .MODEL command you can try [this site](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jan/spice/spice.overview.html).

After a bit of searching, I too was unable to find a model from LT. But TI has provided SPICE models for this part. Two versions can be found at [this website](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/general-electronics-chat/18270-lm317-spice-model.html) and at [this website](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/showthread.php?t=12152&page=6). You can just copy and past the models into your netlist. Let me know if you need help with this part as well.

When it comes down to it though, as our friend [Olin](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/4512/olin-lathrop) would remind you, it is important to realize that SPICE models are just that. They are models and models only, if you only need the behavior of the part (for example linear regulated output) then you easily create that effect on your own.

Here are a couple more resources I have found useful.

1. For finding [datasheets](http://octopart.com/)
2. A huge directory of [SPICE models](http://homepages.which.net/~paul.hills/Circuits/Spice/ModelIndex.html)

Best of luck in finding what you need!

Michael

Answer (score 2):

If you have LTSpice, there is an LM317 model under the [misc] component folder.

And if you don't have LTspice, it's a free download from linear.com.

Cheers.

Comment: There's none in the LTSpice version for Windows 7, 8, 10 that I have downloaded. Will you please help?